Render shows just Grey
I´m having a problem of the render(eevee). on the shading tap render view works normally. but as soon as I render, it just shows the Grey render without any object as you can see in the render tab. Does anyone knows what it might be?
I have used previous file that didn´t have render problem and append all the objects, so that I have every setting same as previous file. but still render shows only grey.

I would appreciate if any one knows what cause this.

Make sure there are no objects with the eye icon off but the camera icon on, that means off for preview render but on for final render. Other than that, make sure to show your render settings and compositor

Also make sure that you don't have a strip in the video sequencer

Non of these are applicable :(

could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
